Is "lack of apathy" a correct usage to express "lack of interest"?
From the online dictionary,
apathy = lack of interest

However I saw a poster in a news article where it was mentioned as -- "lack of apathy".
Is that a correct usage in its context?


'Lack of empathy' might have been intended. 'Lack of apathy' is very clumsy, or at best quirky (say a Pythonesque pun). 'Lack of drought / famine / war ...' don't sound right; 'lack' speaks of misfortune. It's a pejorative, so 'lack of [something undesirable]' is infelicitous.

Definitely not! The translator has completely misunderstood the sense of the word.
